# Origin of "Around the clock" or "Round the clock"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

MW dates "[around the clock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around-the-clock)" back to 1915 and "[round the clock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round-the-clock)" to 1907 but doesn't offer any more details.

Does anyone have any ideas on plausible origins?

Comment: Have you ever looked at a non-digital clock?

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean it's unidentifiable?

The origin seems pretty obvious to me. The hands of a clock go round. The tips of the hands make circles as they turn.  If you say your team is working around the clock, it means that you keep working while the hour hand goes around several times.

Comment: See also Merriam-Webster for when it was first used in print.  Might be an idea to include the link in your answer.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around-the-clock

Comment: I guess some people today may only be familiar with digital clocks, or mostly familiar? That seems the only reason for having to ask.

Answer (score 4):

The origin appears to be literal, its usage is from  WWII according to [Etymonline:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/clock)

> Round-the-clock (adj.) is from 1943, originally in reference to air raids.

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=round%20the%20clock%2C%20around%20the%20clock&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cround%20the%20clock%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caround%20the%20clock%3B%2Cc0) suggest the expression became popular from the 1940s but there are earlier sporadic  usages which date back to early 20th century.

Comment: Try [an 1887 book title](https://archive.org/details/b1109141/mode/2up) *All Round The Clock* by Robert Ellice Mack, illustrated by Harriett M Bennett

Comment: @Henry - yes, Ive seen the book. It appears to be just a rare case at that age.

Comment: @user66974 since Charles Dickens wrote "...whirls through the Law Stationery business at wild speed , all round the clock" in Bleak House (1852), I don't think it was so rare.

Comment: @DavePhD Also there is the book [Twice Round the Clock: Twenty Four Hours in Victorian London](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19196384-twice-round-the-clock) by George Sala which was published in 1859. The Good Reads entry does say that Sala was a protegee of Dickens but I suspect that "round the clock" meaning twelve hours was idiomatic in the mid nineteenth century, at least in London, even if it only rarely made it into print. Perhaps it was considered 'low'.